# getting an error when using toDouble() and toIntOrNull()

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing a simple tip calculator app in android studio ( which is one of the programs in the https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course course ).

But I'm getting an unexpected error, unresolved reference: toDouble, when I try to covert a string to a double. Even after pasting the solution code from the website into my application, the error won't go away. I also tried first converting the string to an int using toInt function but I get the same error.

Here is the code inside MainActivity.kt.

```
package com.example.tiptime

import java.text.NumberFormat
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.tiptime.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener{ calculateTip() }
    }

    fun calculateTip() {
        val stringInTextField = binding.costOfService.text.toString()
        val cost = stringInTextField.toDouble()
    }
}
```

Here is my code in activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cost_of_service"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/cost_of_service"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints="@string/cost_of_service" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/how_was_the_service"
        android:id="@+id/service_question"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cost_of_service"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tip_options"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/option_twenty_percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/service_question"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/option_twenty_percent"
            android:text="@string/amazing_20"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/option_eighteen_percent"
            android:text="@string/great_18"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/option_fifteen_percent"
            android:text="@string/ok_15"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/round_up_switch"
        android:text="@string/round_up_tip"
        android:checked="true"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tip_options" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        android:id="@+id/calculate_button"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/round_up_switch"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tip_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tip_amount"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/calculate_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the screenshot of the error
[image: And here is the screenshot of the error]

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: make sure your project has the kotlin support, also post screenshot of error you are getting

Comment: What is your input and what is you expected output?
Try 'trim()' before 'toDouble()'
`stringInTextField.trim().toDouble()`

Comment: add logs of an error and make sure that your input has only numbers (text not allowed).

Comment: Please add the code of activity_main also . I doubt you have allowed to add other besides number on that

Comment: thanks for the feedback @NiranjanNlc I added activity_mains code too

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki just posted the picture and how do I make sure that my project has kotlin support?

Comment: @F.Mysir when using .trim I get the same message Unresolved reference: trim

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you do not have the latest kotlin support .
Update the Kotlin version to the latest one from :
File ->> Setting -->> Language & Frameworks -->> Kotlin ...

Comment: no, I checked and I have the latest version of plugin installed

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing
`import java.text.NumberFormat`
comment

```
  fun calculateTip() {
    val stringInTextField = binding.costOfService.text.toString()
    val cost = stringInTextField.toDouble()
    }
```

build & clean

uncomment the code in above method you will get correct import

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
val cost = Double.parseDouble(stringInTextField)
```

Comment: This is not a answer to the question

Comment: This should solve the problem op is facing.

Comment: this doesn't work. I get the error, Unresolved reference: parseDouble